# Send files to other directories using ftp

Tags: ftp

I am new to FTP configuration. What I am trying to do is as follows:

I am running a shell script on my localhost and downloading some files to my machine. Now I want a functionality where the files which I downloaded should be stored in a temporary directory, and then it should be transferred to a location(other directory) which I specify. I feel this mechanism is achievable by FTP communication and will be helpful when I host this on a domain, but I am not getting resources from where I can teach myself how to set this up.

Comment: Which OS and which FTP client/server are you using? That might be handy to reach a solution...

Comment: Its Ubuntu 12.04 and I installed vsftpd via CLI. Also installed Filezilla but am having no idea about its usage with my localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, having visited many sites, here are some resources you might find handy:

- For configuring vsftpd, [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-on-ubuntu-12-04)'s a manual of how to install, configure and use.
- About receiving many files recursively via FTP, you can use `wget` (extracted from [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/25199/using-wget-to-recursively-download-whole-ftp-directories) site):

`cd /tmp/ftptransfer`
`wget --mirror --username=foo --password=bar ftp://ftp.originsite.com/path/to/folder`

- About sending many files recursively, many people find the only way of doing so by `tar`-n-send; the only problem is that the files will remain tarred until you extract them by going to the other machine (remotely or via `ssh`) to extract the manually. There is an alternative, not using FTP, [but using `ssh` and pipes](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-52649.html) which lets you have files extracted on target machine:

`tar -cf - /tmp/ftptransfer | ssh geek@targetsite "cd target_dir; tar -xf -"`

- Explained:

  - `tar` is the application to make tar files
  - `-c`: create file
  - `-f -`: file name is "stdout"
  - `/tmp/ftptransfer`: include this folder and all subdirectories in the tar
  - `|`: Make a pipe to the next program (connect stdout to stdin)
  - `ssh`: Secure Shell program
  - `geek@targetsite`: username @ machinename where you want to connect to
  - `"..."` command to send to the remote host

    - `cd target_dir`: changes the dir of output
    - `tar -xf -`: extracts the file received by "stdin"

For configuring SSH on Ubuntu, have a look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html).

If you need more help, don't be afraid to ask! :)

Comment: First of all, Thanks a lot for the time @SonicARG. I had configured vsftpd and my shell script already has the wget command. Consider this example, I am hosting this on a domain and you are requesting the files from that server. Now suppose you are a Windows user, and you want to download files to a specific directory. Here I dont have an option of doing ssh on that remote Windows system right? This is my problem, I hope you understood my point.

Comment: Well, not everything is lost... Thanks to the guys at [CygWin](http://cygwin.com), we have a fully POSIX-compliant layer running over Windows, so (nearly) every POSIX-compliant program can be compiled over Windows as well as Linux. So, there is a `cygwin-sshd` server you can install in Windows and do ssh to the machine running Windows as well ([here](http://www.noah.org/ssh/cygwin-sshd.html)'s a guide of how-to use sshd in CygWin). BTW, FTP is an OS-free protocol, so FTP can be used in any host/target OS.

Comment: But I am developing it as a Web Service you see. If a user wants to make use of this service and download my files, I cant ask him to first install cygwin for that right? I had checked Cygwin and my understanding as of now is that you are suggesting me that if a Windows user just wants to download files, he needs to install Cygwin first and then download the files he need! Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks again!!